# I own a WordPress blogging website which is showing an error of web stories sitemap index I can't understand what's and where the issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, sitemap

[In this imagethe red highlighted part is the issue on my website aboutGoogle web stories sitemap indexing which I'munable to get so pleasecan anyone help me in fixing this issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFSY7.png)

I asked about it to mu domain and hosting service providers but they gave me the link of this website and told that I'll surely get a solution on this platform because it's a development related issue which domain and hosting service providers cannot correct so I had to ask here they said that's why I am asking for solution here.

Comment: Press the three vertical dots on right column and get the details.

Comment: The files do not exist? Create them or remove the entries?